# How to play random sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, discord.js, fs

I'm making a discord bot, and I want it to play a random mp3 file when it joins channel.

```
case"join":
            message.delete( {timeout: 5000})
            const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
            if(voiceChannel) {
                const connection = await voiceChannel.join()
                const files = fs.readdirSync("./sounds/")
                const randFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
                const dispatcher = connection.play(randFile)
            } else {
                message.reply("you need to be in a voice channel!").then(message => message.delete( {timeout: 5000}))
            }
            break;
```

When I type $join in chat, it joins voice channel that I'm in but doesn't play anything.

Comment: Getting any errors?

Comment: No it doesn't give any errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the file path.

```js
case "join":
message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
if (voiceChannel) {
  const connection = await voiceChannel.join()
  const files = fs.readdirSync("./sounds/")
  const randFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
  const dispatcher = connection.play(`./sounds/${randFile}`) // Obviously change `.mp3` to the file extension of your sound files.
} else {
  message.reply("you need to be in a voice channel!").then(message => message.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
}
break;
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Should be v12(I downloaded it in april), I'm not sure how to check it, node.js is v12.16.2

Comment: did you install `@discordjs/opus`?

Comment: Yes, when I do just `const dispatcher = connection.play(`./sounds/example.mp3`)` it's working fine, the problem is only in this case with fs.readdirSync/FileSync and the Math.random.

Comment: console log `randFile` and `files`, check if they return anything.

Comment: Output is: [ 'NakopuTi.mp3', 'PulpFiction.mp3', 'Salinger.mp3', 'YouSuffer.mp3' ]
2, I did it multiple times and the number is changing too

Comment: The file extension would already be in the array from readdirSync

Comment: Still not playing anything, interesting is that when the bot joins, the green circle around the logo(speaking) appears. I changed the names of files to 1.mp3, 2.mp3 etc. still didn't work, the output is: [ '0.mp3', '1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3' ]
1.mp3

Comment: what @vpzomtrrfrt said is true, this edit should work, if it doesn't then I'm not sure what else could be the issue

Comment: JESUS CHRIST ITS WORKING NOW!!! I screamed out loud when it worked :D, thank you very much man I've been working on it a few hours today. Again thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks to @vpzomtrrfrt too. Also welcome to SO. If an answer solves your question accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what works and that it has been answered

Comment: Yeah of course I appreciate everyone who's helped me, but you extra for the instant live support. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer, again thank you all.